# Navigation not working in react-bootstrap suddenly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

My react app used to work with react-bootstrap and now suddenly the navigation is not working. Here is my package.json. At the moment, it only shows the "Roommates" brand but not other items like sign in or contact or about and there is a small button next to it, when i click on the button, it expands for a second, the menus show and disappear again, and also when the screen is small, the hamburger menu doesnt show.

```
{
 "name": "newreactstuff",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
 "react": "^16.2.0",
 "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
 "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
 "react-router": "^4.2.0",
 "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
 "react-scripts": "1.1.1"
  },
 "scripts": {
 "start": "react-scripts start",
 "build": "react-scripts build",
 "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
 "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
"proxy": "http://localhost:3001/"
}
```

Here is my Nav component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Link
 } from 'react-router-dom';
import { NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { MenuItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Nav, Navbar, NavItem, NavDropdown, MenuItem, FormControl, FormGroup, 
Button } from 'react-bootstrap';


class Navigation extends Component {

render() {
 return (
  <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
   <Navbar.Header>
    <Navbar.Brand>
     <Link to="/">Roommates</Link>
   </Navbar.Brand>
   <Navbar.Toggle />
 </Navbar.Header>
 <Navbar.Collapse>
   <Nav pullRight>
      <li><Link to="/">Sign In</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
   </Nav>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
 </Navbar>
     )
   }
 }

export default Navigation;
```